# Get Facebook user access token using Python and local host with Firefox

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to generate an access token to be used with my application which downloads insights data programmatically from Facebook. I'd like to generate the token so that a user won't have to copy-paste it from the graph api explorer every time, as it suggested in many guides.

The code I'm using is the following

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from urllib.request import urlopen, HTTPError
from webbrowser import open_new

REDIRECT_URL = 'https://localhost:8080/auth/facebook/callback'
PORT = 8080

def get_access_token_from_url(url):
    """
    Parse the access token from Facebook's response
    Args:
        uri: the facebook graph api oauth URI containing valid client_id,
             redirect_uri, client_secret, and auth_code arguments
    Returns:
        a string containing the access key 
    """
    token = str(urlopen(url).read(), 'utf-8')
    return token.split(':')[1].split(',')[0].replace('"','')

class HTTPServerHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    """
    HTTP Server callbacks to handle Facebook OAuth redirects
    """
    def __init__(self, request, address, server, a_id, a_secret):
        self.app_id = a_id
        self.app_secret = a_secret
        super().__init__(request, address, server)

    def do_GET(self):
        GRAPH_API_AUTH_URI = ('https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/oauth/' 
            + 'access_token?client_id=' + self.app_id + '&redirect_uri=' 
            + REDIRECT_URL + '&client_secret=' + self.app_secret + '&code=')
        
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        if 'code' in self.path:
            self.auth_code = self.path.split('=')[1]
            #Display to the user that they no longer need the browser window
            self.wfile.write(bytes('<html><h1>You may now close this window.'
                              + '</h1></html>', 'utf-8'))
            self.server.access_token = get_access_token_from_url(
                    GRAPH_API_AUTH_URI + self.auth_code)

class TokenHandler:
    """
    Class used to handle Facebook oAuth
    """
    def __init__(self, a_id, a_secret):
        self._id = a_id
        self._secret = a_secret

    def get_access_token(self):
        """
         Fetches the access key using an HTTP server to handle oAuth
         requests
            Args:
                appId:      The Facebook assigned App ID
                appSecret:  The Facebook assigned App Secret
        """

        ACCESS_URI = ('https://www.facebook.com/v7.0/dialog/' 
            + 'oauth?client_id=' + self._id + '&redirect_uri='
            + REDIRECT_URL) 
        
        open_new(ACCESS_URI)
        
        httpServer = HTTPServer(
                ('localhost', PORT),
                lambda request, address, server: HTTPServerHandler(
                    request, address, server, self._id, self._secret))
        
        #This function will block until it receives a request
        httpServer.handle_request()
        #Return the access token
        return httpServer.access_token
```

However I get this error after I login into Facebook (basically when I should retrieve the 'code' parameter.

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to localhost:8080. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
```

I also tried to disable TLS 1.3 but didn't work. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Instead of diabling TLS you should upgrade it. This errors occurs when you use wrong port or use old version of TLS. Could you change the port with 443 or 8443.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, still get the same error.

Comment: Wondering why that error message says _“during a connection **to** localhost:8080”_? That sounds like it had rather little to do with Facebook (they don’t make requests _to_ your server during the login process), and is a local problem in your browser instead somewhow?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the contex argument to urlopen on line 17:

```
import ssl

certificate = ssl.create_default_context(purpose=Purpose.SERVER_AUTH, cafile=None, capath=None, cadata=None)

token = str(urlopen(url, context=certificate).read(), 'utf-8')
```

This is an empty ssl ceritificate that won't trigger any error.

Keep in mind you may be using a deprecated version of tls, I'd advise you to check that.

Try changing the port you are using as it may help:

```
PORT = 8443
```

If none of the above helps try changing all of your urls to http instead of htpps like this:

```
REDIRECT_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/auth/facebook/callback'
```

Keep in mind that not using the https protocol is a big security risk and exposes your users to man in the middle attacks so I don't recommend it but it's your choice.

Keep in mind that using urllib for such endeavours is not wise, I'd recommend using the [request package](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

One last thing, I see a lot of younior developers using non optimal naming convetions, I'd recommend naming function, variables, classes etc... whit human readable names, it's gonna take longer but is a best practise and helps a lot in the long run as you won't need to go back to where you declared a function if you forget what it does.

Edit:
In the case you're considering using the request library, you can add the verify parameter to false, effectively ignoring the ssl certificate:

```
requests.get('https://kennethreitz.com', verify=False)
```

Comment: _“If none of the above helps try changing all of your urls to http instead of htpps like this”_ - I think Facebook does not allow that any more, not even for localhost URLs. If you want to use Facebook login, you need to use HTTPS.

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/pg/SamsungGlobal/posts/ seems to work  but it redirects to the https page

Comment: I am not talking about Facebook page URLs here, I am talking about the redirect URL. HTTPS is mandatory for that part of the login flow, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#https